# Split an R package into two packages without disrupting users

Tags: r, package

Suppose I'm currently developing a package called `mypackage`. As time goes by, many different functions have landed in there, and I want to reorganize it. So I'd like to create a new package called `newpackage` in which I would move some of the functions of `mypackage` (and include new ones later).

The problem is that I don't want original users of `mypackage` to get `object not found` errors when they want to use one of the moved functions.

So, I thought about doing the following :

- create `newpackage` and move the functions
- add into `mypackage` DESCRIPTION file : `Depends: newpackage`

As such, when people would install, upgrade or load `mypackage`, `newpackage` would be installed or loaded too, and all the functions would be available.

Do you think it would work, or would there be some problems I don't think about ?

Thanks !

Comment: One package that comes to mind is `gregmisc`. Read the package's [CRAN listing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gregmisc/index.html) to get an idea of how it was handled. Is this along the lines of what you're thinking?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes, this is almost exactly what I was talking about. Thanks a lot, it proves that the `Depends` trick works, and will provide a model if I decide to go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it so that it is not recommended to remove functions from a package without labeling them first to be depreciated?! So, maybe you proceed as you planned but before removing them from the `mypackage`, you could first mark them there as depreciated and then remove them from it finally in the next version of the package. And during the migrating phase you could use the namespace of the packages to refer already to the function in `newpackage` as you planned.

Comment: Yes, you're right, using `.Deprecated` with an informative message would certainly be cleaner.